# Control caffe display while training

Tags: caffe

I am using caffe to train a deep network, and have set the display at 200 iterations in my solver prototext file. However, instead of getting the loss and accuracy, I am getting a large number of lines of the form

`solver.cpp:245]  Train net output #{no.}: prob = {no.}.`

The prob values are the probabilities of output of softmax layer(the last layer in my network).
This display is of no real use to me. I am interested in seeing only the rate at which the accuracy is evolving with the number of iterations. Can someone suggest a way in which I may print only the relevant parameters to stdout? Is there a way to control in general what is printed by caffe to stdout?

Thanks.

(Note: I am using caffe executable for training on ubuntu)

Comment: Is the softmax layer a loss layer?

Comment: Yes, the layer is a softmax loss layer.

Comment: Include your network design file (.prototxt) in the question.